# How to draw industry schematic diagram in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams, plot

Is it possible to create the following diagram in LaTeX ? I am interested in the main body, any colour inside the box is fine.

[image]

Comment: Hi giannis :) and [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function. posting MWE may satisfy the downvoter.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts too keep question very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about). I have rephrased question and its tone to get noticed.

Comment: I'm gonna really consider all the above. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture} [align=left] 
    \node [draw] (home) {Home\\(capital-abundant)};
    \draw (home.east) -- ++(2,0) node [above] (cloth) {Cloth}
        -- ++(2,0) node [above] (food) {Food} -- ++(1,0) node [coordinate] (topend) {};
    \node[below=of home] (mid) {};
    \draw[dashed] (cloth |- mid) -- (topend |- mid);
    \node [draw, below=of mid] (foreign) {Foreign\\(labor-abundant)};
    \draw (foreign.east) -- (topend |- foreign);
    \draw[->] (cloth) -- (cloth |- foreign);
    \draw[->] (food |- mid) -- (food);
    \node [coordinate,right=0.1cm of cloth] (c1) {};
    \draw[->] (c1 |- foreign) -- (c1 |- mid);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace, amplitude=4pt}] 
            (topend) -- (topend |- mid) node[midway, right=3pt]{Interindustry};
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace, amplitude=4pt}] 
            (topend |- mid) -- (topend |- foreign) node[midway, right=3pt]{Intraindustry};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Nice answer, but it is better to turn the code snippet into [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also showing the result helps in making the answer clearer. `:)`

Comment: Would be lovely if we could integrate tex previews directly into the site.

Comment: @u0b34a0f6ae [It's work in progress thru online compiler](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3167/15717)

Comment: @u0b34a0f6ae thank you very much. I'm gonna try it!

Comment: giannis, it should be easy to use the line widths and background colors you'd like.